# Kubernetes can't bridge externalName service with https

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I need to connect an EKS deployment to Aws OpenSearch(akka Elasticsearch). The connection is fine, however since my Opensearch instance requires Https connection the application is not considering the connection as secure.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opensearch-service
  namespace: development
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  type: ExternalName
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalName: my_internal_aws_url_for_elasticsearch.es.amazonaws.com
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

The connection is fine, if I try to connect ignoring the certificate the connection is fine:

```
curl -k https://opensearch-service
```

So, Is there a way to keep the Https working properly using a Service to connect to external name?

Comment: Who is CA for your service ?

Comment: There is no CA considered, that's my full yaml, is there a way to set one?